# Parameter parsing when using AWS SSM send-command from Terraform

Tags: aws-cli, terraform

I am using AWS SSM send-command to run a PowerShell script on an AWS instance.

The following commanad works fine in a command shell but when called in Terraform gets an error.

> aws ssm send-command --instance-ids ${self.id} --document-name AWS->RunPowerShellScript --parameters commands='C:\Installers\bootstrap_test.ps1 >test'

when called in Terraform using:

> provisioner "local-exec" {
>      command = "aws ssm send-command --instance-ids ${self.id} --document-name AWS-RunPowerShellScript --parameters commands='C:\Installers\bootstrap_test.ps1 test' --output-s3-bucket-name ellucian-ecrm-lab --output-s3-key-prefix bootstraplogs"
>    }

The error returned is:

> exit status 255. Output: usage: aws [options]   [ ...] [parameters]
>   To see help text, you can run:
>
> aws help
>    aws  help
>    aws   help
>
> Unknown options: test'

So I don't thing Terraform is parsing the string the way AWS needs it. what can I do to format this string correctly in Terraform?

Comment: i managed to get aws command working by escaping the quotes using backslash "\"

Comment: @krisdigitx Can you expand on this? I tried this approach but got this error: `Error parsing parameter '--parameters': Expected: ',', received: '"' for input:`

Comment: `--parameters commands="\"${COMMAND}\""` Where COMMAND is a double quoted string containing the actual command ie: `"C:\Installers\bootstrap_test.ps1 >test"`?

Answer (score 1):

Try by double quoting the commands, e.g.:

```
... --parameters commands='"C:\Installers\bootstrap_test.ps1 > test"'
```

Here is the example with the loop:

> `aws ssm send-command --instance-ids "i-01234" --document-name "AWS-RunPowerShellScript" --query "Command.CommandId" --output text --parameters commands='"While ($i -le 100) {$i; $i += 1}"'`

Or the opposite, e.g.

```
--parameters commands="'While ($i -le 100) {$i; $i += 1}'"
```